# Scipy.spatial.distance calculate with lower precision?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, precision

Hobbyist programmer here. I'm calculating a cosine similarity between columns of a large pandas DataFrame (~15k columns, ~100k entries) using Scipy's spatial.distance.cosine function. However, calculations take long, and I'm wondering if there's a way to reduce precision in order to make them faster? I'd happily change output's dtype from float64 to float16.

My code looks like this:

```
cosine_similarity = pd.DataFrame()
for index1, col1 in df.iteritems():
    row = {}
    u = col1.as_matrix()
    for index2, col2 in df.iteritems():
        v = col2.as_matrix()
        similarity = 1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u,v) 
        # i guess i could cast this to float16 afterwards
        row[index2] = similarity
    row_series = pd.Series(row, index=[index1])
    cosine_similarity = pd.concat([cosine_similarity, row_series])
    print(index1) #for display reasons
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
similarity = 1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u,v, dtype=float16)
```

What's the approach I should take?

Comment: You can see here [https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L476-L506](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L476-L506) that scipy cosine returns double =(

Comment: Oh, but it appears that if I'll have the numpy array in desired dtype, and write my own cosine similarity function (like: `def cosine_similarity(u,v): numpy.dot(u,v)/(numpy.linalg.norm(u)*numpy.linalg.norm(v))` will also be float 16. I'll try doing that.

Comment: @Sklert that same document also contains this: *Computing
distances over a large collection of vectors is inefficient for these
functions. Use ``pdist`` for this purpose.*